# ASP.NET controller, AJAX GET works, but POST does not (404)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a .NET Core MVC project (`dotnet 2.0.0`) and I want to send an AJAX request from `.cshtml` view to some controller method.

I can do it using **GET** with no problems.

AJAX:

```
var msg = {
    someField: "some value",
    someAnotherField: "another value"
    };

jQuery.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("DoStuff", "Some")',
    dataType: 'application/json',
    data: msg,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult DoStuff(Msg post)
    {
        // some processing here
        // ...
        return Json("some result");
    }

    public class Msg
    {
        public string someField { get; set; }
        public string someAnotherField { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But when I try to do it using **POST**...

Modified AJAX (just changed its type):

```
// ...
type: 'POST',
// ...
```

Modified controller method (just added an attribute):

```
// ...
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DoStuff(Msg post)
// ...
```

...I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`.

I tried adding `[FromBody]` attribute to controller, but it didn't change anything (and also **GET** method works fine without it). I also tried `JSON.stringify()` for my AJAX `data` - no difference.

So, I assume, it has something to do with the routing? Or perhaps passing JSON objects as parameters to controller is different for **POST** requests?

### Update

I have created a small project ([uploaded to Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nlbrtxojpxczct2/AjaxGetPost.zip?dl=0)) to reproduce this issue, but I couldn't reproduce it. Everything works fine, and simply changing to `type: 'POST'` and adding `[HttpPost]` is enough.

So, my problem not with the **GET**/**POST** semantics, but with some settings/routing in my main project. I'll try to find out, what exactly is wrong, and will share my results.

Comment: For a post, use a routing attribute, `[HttpPost]`

Comment: It's there, as you can see in my "modified controller" code.

Comment: Is "Modified controller" in a different controller?  If so then the ajax  isn't going to hit it since it is pointing at "SomeController".  Or do you mean that it is the exact same controller but you modified it by adding the tag?

Comment: This is the same controller, I just added a `[HttpPost]` attribute.

Comment: Check the network tab in the console and see what the request itself looks like.  Compare what it looks like when the ajax is get and when it is post.  With a get, it should be adding `?msg=....' but with a post you should have JSON.

Comment: Yes, that's the way POST request looks like, I checked. But it anyway fails with `Failed to load resource ... 404`.

Comment: Did you try use `@Url.Action("DoStuff", "Some")` instead of `@Url.Action("DoStuff", "SomeController")`?

Comment: @sigurd, yeah, sorry for that, I actually have exactly `Some` and not `SomeController`. So, resulting URL is this one: `/Some/DoStuff`, and it works with **GET** and gives 404 with **POST**.

Comment: @retif do you have a repository somewhere which can reproduce this behavior? I tested on my machine and everything works just fine with [HttpPost] attribute. Also, which version of jquery are you using? (Not that it should matter, just in case)

Comment: @sigurd, I started to make one and then tried to reproduce the issue myself, and I couldn't. Сhanging `type: 'POST'` and adding `[HttpPost]` is enough, everything works fine in this small project. But it doesn't work in my main project. But then obviously something is wrong with some settings in my main project, and not with the GET/POST.

Comment: I would do a find all on the entire solution and try to find some weird hidden reference to that controller action.  Possibly something somewhere is routing something in an unexpected way.  Are you using routeconfig?   Any middleware or filters that could be redirecting?

Comment: I only have standard route in `Startup.cs` (`{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}`). And I tried renaming controller method to a really unique name - still no luck. Very weird indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost two years later, while working on a different project, I finally found what was wrong back then.

So I got a similar situation, with the only difference that this time I was using .NET Core 2.2 (*back than it was 2.0*), and the error I got was `405 Method Not Allowed` (*instead of `404` from 2.0*), which helped me to realize that this is because of the missing antiforgery token (*I have those enabled globally*).

Having found the actual reason, it was easy to find the solution - I only needed to add `RequestVerificationToken` header to XMLHttpRequest.

`Some.cshtml`:

```js
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Xsrf

@{
    string antiForgeryToken = Xsrf.GetAndStoreTokens(Context).RequestToken;
}

...

<script>

    // with jQuery
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("DoSome", "SomeController")',
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            "RequestVerificationToken": "@(antiForgeryToken)"
        },
        type: "POST",
        // ...

    // without jQuery
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = "json";
    xhr.open("POST", '@Url.Action("DoSome", "SomeController")';
    xhr.setRequestHeader("RequestVerificationToken", "@(antiForgeryToken)");
    // ...

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the AJAX request change the data property as below for POST

```
data: JSON.stringify(msg)
```

Comment: Yeah, I already tried that, but it didn't make any difference. And also It works fine without `JSON.stringify()` using **GET**.

Comment: Can you please try changing the name of the POST method? I had same problem and by changing the method name solved the problem.

Comment: Not only that, but I also tried moving method to another controller with a really unique name (both controller and method), but still failed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    url = '@Url.Action("ControllerName", "MethodName")';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        data: dataParameter,
        success: function (data) {
            var vmMsg = data;
            if (vmMsg.MessageType == 1) {
                ShowNotification(1, vmMsg.CurrentMessage);

    }

        },
        error: function () {

        }
    });
```

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MethodName(Param)
    {
        var data = _iMonthlyBillProvisionManager.ClientInterface(Param);
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

Comment: That's what I already have and it does not work in my particular project, see the Update appendix.