# AJAX POST request returns 404 .NET 6

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I have this issue:

I am using .NET 6 with MVC and I am making use of FullcalendarIo. I have a controller for making free slots in the calendar. This is the code in the controller:

```cs
 [Authorize(Roles = DoctorRoleName)]
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public async Task < ActionResult < AppointmentSlotInputModel >> GenerateSlots(AppointmentSlotInputModel model) {
     //await this.appointmentService.GenerateSlots(model.Start, model.End, model.SlotDurationMinutes);
     return Json("Hello");
 }
```

And this is my JS Code that makes the POST request

```js
const params = {
    start: startDate,
    end: endDate,
    slotDurationMinutes: scale
};

const response = await fetch('/Appointment/GenerateSlots', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'RequestVerificationToken': document.getElementById("RequestVerificationToken").value
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(params)
});
```

In the network tab the request to /Appointment/GenerateSlots I get first code 302 - Redirect and then 404 Not Found. The request url seems correct - https://localhost:44376/Appointment/GenerateSlots.

f I change the method to GET and put the [HttpGet] attribute above the action in the controller I get the JSON result. In the Startup.cs I am using these:

```cs
    services.AddAntiforgery(options => {
        options.HeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN";
    });

    services.Configure < CookiePolicyOptions > (options => {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });
```

But event if I comment them out the result is the same - first 302 then 404. I have tried a lot of the code that is written here on the site for people with similar issues, but it hasn't helped. Where am I mistaking?
I am using standard routing:

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "areas",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Edit: I have found a similar thread here - [ASP.NET controller, AJAX GET works, but POST does not (404)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47514158/asp-net-controller-ajax-get-works-but-post-does-not-404)
But this doesn't seem to be the case for me.

Comment: The problem is about the routing part. Not here

Comment: If I change the method to Get and put an attribute [HttpGet] it returns the correct result.

Comment: So in your router, you don't handle this address for POST requests. Just edit the method attached to this URL in router section

Comment: I am using just the default routing : endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); I tried with the [Route("appointment/generateSlots")] attribute, but is all the same.

Comment: Could you try GenerateSlots([FromBody] AppointmentSlotInputModel model)?

Comment: Is your backend running on the same port? if not then you will face a CORS issue as well, better add headers for that as well

Comment: I tried [FromBody]. It is all the same. Everything is running on localhost:44736. The app is not deployed.

Comment: I did a route in the startup.cs and that made it work, but now it doesn't bind the input data. Also I experimented in creating an ApiController with the same options and when I send request via Postman I always get BadRequest. I read and that is normal for invalid data input, but I made this action:         [HttpPost("hi")]
        public string Hi()
        {
            return "HI";
        } and the ApiController still returns BadRequest.

Comment: i think you enabled SSL, so 302, tries to redirect to https, but you probably dont have it running, so you get a 404.

Comment: I managed to get it working. Now the issue is that it just doesn't post the data. I even implemented an ApiController, but when I post any data it just returns BadRequest, no matter the data I post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a my solution. In my Startup.cs I have this code:

```
    services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
    {
        options.HeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN";
    });
```

And the BadRequest from the Controller came because of the AntiForgeryToken validation. In my AJAX call my header for the AF Token was wrong: It was 'RequestVerificationToken', but it should have been 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' or the other way around. But still now I have the proper result and no more BadRequest.